# How to get the details of a token transaction[like amount sent] on Near protocol

Tags: nearprotocol

Im trying to get the details of a token transaction on near.
Details like the token amount that was sent.

The JSON RPC endpoints only returns details related to the amount of NEAR involved in the transaction.

Some of the tokens(like token.sweat) emit a log that contains the token amount involved in the transaction, but this is not consistent across all tokens on Near.

Is there a standard way of getting this?

I'd imagine there is, because explorers on near are able to get these details too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard for [event logs](https://github.com/near/NEPs/issues/141) in NEAR.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/blob/63ba6ecc9439ec1c319c1094d581653698229473/near-contract-standards/src/fungible_token/core_impl.rs#L104) log of the `ft_transfer` event for Fungible Tokens (NEP141) on NEAR.

```
FtTransfer {
    old_owner_id: sender_id,
    new_owner_id: receiver_id,
    amount: &U128(amount),
    memo: memo.as_deref(),
}
.emit();
```

Here is an example output.

```
Log [dev-1671032805857-80440743716599]: EVENT_JSON:{"standard":"nep141","version":"1.0.0","event":"ft_transfer","data":[{"old_owner_id":"dev-1671032805857-80440743716599","new_owner_id":"new_owner_id.testnet","amount":"10000000000000000000","memo":"Your memo here"}]}
```

You can parse the log in the event JSON to get the params you want.